# UIImageView and ScrollView weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a imageView Carousel with a PageControl in the titleView. Everything seem to work now, beside the alignment of the images. What am i doing wrong here? Look at the bottom image where it does not seem to fit it all?

**Cell**

```
class ImageViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageScroll:UIScrollView?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        //scrollView

        imageScroll!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        imageScroll!.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        imageScroll!.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        imageScroll!.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        imageScroll!.pagingEnabled = true
        imageScroll!.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
        imageScroll!.bounces = false


    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }





}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath in viewController**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageViewCell



    cell.imageScroll!.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count), 200)
    cell.imageScroll!.delegate = self
    for (index, element) in pageImages.enumerate() {

        let newImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(index) * self.view.frame.width + 4, 0, self.view.frame.width, 200))
        newImage.image = element
        cell.imageScroll!.addSubview(newImage)


    }


    return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: maybe the `+4` on the `UIImage` x position?

Comment: oops yea, but doesnt remove everything. it is on both images

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the [`clipsToBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) property of the `UIImageView` to `true`, this property determines whether subviews are confined to the bounds of the view. You need to set too the [`contentMode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode) to specify how a view adjusts its content when its size changes to any you want, something like this:

```
newImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
newImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Are you set any constraints in Interface Builder?

Comment: inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` please print the `newImage.frame` and share the values.

Comment: yes i've set the imageScroll trailing, leading, bottom and top space to -8

Comment: the output `(0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 200.0), (375.0, 0.0, 375.0, 200.0)`

Comment: so better be something with the ìmagescroll`i guess?

Comment: Yes I supposed your issue is with the `UIScrollView`